# Merging multiple commits into one before pushing

Tags: git

I had a master branch. And I started to work on a feature on this branch (I forgot to create separate branch and to play on this branch). Before I came to the end of feature implementation, I had a dozen on commits to master with dummy names etc... And now I would like to push this feature to my master origin. But I don't want to push whole commits history. Is there a way to "rollback" intermediate from git log?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have 12 commits it will probably be fastest to do

```
git reset --soft @{u}
git commit -m "YOUR COMMIT MESSAGE"
git push
```

This will squash an arbitrary number of commits without you having to do anything on a per-commit basis.

Comment: `@{u}` is shorthand for `@{upstream}` which in his case should be `origin/master`.  It will create a single new commit with content being his final changes.

Comment: Oh I see. Very clever, educational. I suggest the option of branching beforehand, so the local repository keeps the full history for the future.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `git rebase` with the squash feature. See the [manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase).

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is `squash` your commits together. Suppose you made 10 commits since you started; then you will do:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~10
```

- -i : interactive rebasing
- HEAD~10 : starting from the 10th commit before the current one (HEAD)

now you will be in an editor with a line for each commit. You should replace the words `pick`. For the first line you will type `edit` (so you can change the commit message), for all the others `fixup` (or `f`). Thus all the latter commits will be squashed into the first one; and the commit message will be removed (so only the commit message you edited will remain).

So the file you are editing should look like this:

```
edit  2fa588e start of devel
fixup c420848 bugfix
f     78c41af bugfix
f     6bff2f0 bugfix blah blah
```